# Node Express- delete route works but throws an error

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I made an api app in Node Express. Routes post and put are working perfectly. Delete route is also working but I dont see confirmation of resolved promise, instead after few secs I see those errors

1. Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://ahi' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
   PageAdmin.js:179 fail Error: Network Error
2. DELETE https://ahi net::ERR_FAILED

I was already dealing with that problem at beginning of setting up app on server so I searched how to deal with it. Here is my middleware code on server for setting up headers

```
function setHeaders(app) {
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Methods",
      "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE"
    );
    res.setHeader(
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin,Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, x-auth-token"
    );
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    // handle OPTIONS method
    if ("OPTIONS" == req.method) {
      return res.sendStatus(200);
    } else {
      next();
    }
  });
}
```

Here is the code for routes

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const auth = require("../middleware/auth");
const { ProgrammingTool, validate } = require("../models/programmingTool");

const msg400 = "Bad request";
const msg400InData = "Item already exists in database";
const msg404 = "Could not find item in database";
const msg500 = "Something went wrong";

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const tools = await ProgrammingTool.find();
    res.send(tools);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("failed getting tools", e);
    res.status(500).send(msg500);
  }
});

router.get("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  if (!mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(404).send(msg404);
  const tool = await ProgrammingTool.findById(req.params.id);
  if (!tool) return res.status(404).send(msg404);
  res.send(tool);
});

router.post("/", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const validation = validate(req.body);
  if (validation.error) return res.status(400).send(msg400);

  try {
    const toolInData = await ProgrammingTool.findOne({ name: req.body.name });
    if (toolInData) return res.status(400).send(msg400InData);
  } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500).send(msg500);
  }

  const tool = new ProgrammingTool({ name: req.body.name });

  try {
    await tool.validate();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("did not pass mongoose validation at posting", e);
    return res.status(400).send(msg400);
  }
  try {
    const result = await tool.save();
    res.send(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("failed to post tool");
    res.status(500).send(msg500);
  }
});

router.delete("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id;
  let tool;
  try {
    tool = await ProgrammingTool.findById(id);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("could not find the tool with provided id", e);
    res.status(404).send(msg404);
  }
  try {
    await tool.delete();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("failed deleting tool", e);
    res.status(500).send(msg500);
  }
});

router.put("/:id", auth, async (req, res) => {
  const validation = validate(req.body);
  if (validation.error) return res.status(400).send(msg400);

  const id = req.params.id;
  const tool = await ProgrammingTool.findById(id);
  if (!tool) res.status(404).send(msg404);

  tool.name = req.body.name;

  try {
    await tool.validate();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("did not pass mongoose validation at putting", e);
    return res.status(400).send(msg400);
  }

  try {
    const result = await tool.save();
    res.send(result);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log("failed to save edited tool");
    res.status(500).send(msg500);
  }
});

router.delete("/", auth, (req, res) => {
  res.status(400).send(msg400);
});

router.put("/", auth, (req, res) => {
  res.status(400).send(msg400);
});
```

What really suprises me is that the error is getting thrown but route does it job, item is deleted from database.

Comment: Your delete has missing return in first `catch` block. So it sends back error. And second catch block if throw error it also send results back. You can only send back response once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `delete` route there are 2 problems.

1. you are not using `return` so even after the first error it goes to the second try catch block. Add `return` to both `res.status(..).send(..)`
2. For a successful Delete operation you are not returning a 2xx status code. So if there is a successful deletion the request will be stuck cause you are not returning anything, after some time probably it will time out.

Comment: Yep that was exactly the problem, thank you